Пунктуация в данном предложении
"Написать 50 наречий, 25 из которых пишутся не с наречиями на -о и -е раздельно и 25 наречий из которых - слитно!" - правильно ли я составил такое предложение? По запятым. Мне кажется, что нужно было поставить вторую запятую перед "и 25 наречий из которых - слитно!"

пишутся не с наречиями - вот это некорректно. и это тоже - 25 наречий из которых


"Написать 50 наречий, 25 из которых пишутся не с наречиями на -о и -е
раздельно и 25 наречий из которых - слитно!"

А чему мы так радуемся? После "слитно" убираем восклицательный знак.
А запятая - нет, не нужна; столько-то и столько-то.
Стилистика страдает, как уже было отмечено в комменте, - переписываем!
Написать 50 наречий на -о и -е с отрицанием не, 25 из которых пишутся с не раздельно и 25 - слитно.

Галина Аванесова: «Написать 50 наречий на -о и -е с частицей не, 25 из которых пишутся раздельно и 25 - слитно». === Корректнее будет, если «с частицей» заменить на «с отрицанием», как это сделано в ПАС: ведь если «не» с каким-то словом пишется слитно, то частицей его уже называть нельзя – оно становится приставкой.

Я сохранила оригинал, переставив слова и сократив. Может, не сразу деток грузят частицами-приставками.

Нет, не сохранили. В оригинале слова частица не было!

Ок, уже исправляю.

Галина, я немного подкорректировал Ваш ответ. Хотелось бы  ещё и союз «и» в концовке заменить на «а»…
